# Awesomium Browser Engine - Navigation

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010, awesomium

I am currently building a web browser in VB.net and I am having a hard time getting `e.SuppressKeyPress = True` to work. I am using this code on my URL bar so users can hit enter and navigate to the desired page. My entire code:

```
    Private Sub AddressBar_KeyUp(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles AddressBar.KeyUp
    On Error Resume Next
    If e.KeyCode = 13 Then
        Dim textArray = AddressBar.Text.Split(" ")
        If (AddressBar.Text.Contains(".") = True And AddressBar.Text.Contains(" ") = False And AddressBar.Text.Contains(" .") = False And AddressBar.Text.Contains(". ") = False) Or textArray(0).Contains(":/") = True Or textArray(0).Contains(":\") Then
            Navigate(AddressBar.Text)
        Else
            Navigate("http://www.google.com/search?q=" + AddressBar.Text)
        End If
        WebControl.Focus()
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I have tried moving the `e.SuppressKeyPress = True` to multiple different places and none of them work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there any reason why you would be making your own browser these days? :)

Comment: Actually, I am only doing it because I have nothing better to do.

Comment: Join an open source project and help develop browsers like Google Chrome. Or any other open source project. Or if you don't like open source, create an application that wasn't there before you. Or an improved version of an app you worked with. Do your research prior to that, but keep it simple. Don't attempt to start with rewriting Visual Studio and alike. Google is your friend. Reinventing the wheel is the worst investment of your time.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot suppress the key in the KEYUP event, the key has already been processed. It is pretty dumb of Microsoft to even give you this option.  Try this code in a sample app and compare the results

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = "b" Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyUp
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.C Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I see that I can't do that now, is there any way to get rid of the sound? I'm using "The Web Browser Project" source code because that browser uses the suppress key press function.

Comment: What do mean, "is there any way to get rid of the sound"? What sound?

Comment: When you hit enter in a text box that is not multiline.

Comment: If you use the KEYDOWN or KEYPRESS example I provided (assuming you are preventing an enter), you will notice there is no sound either.

Comment: Okay. I was familiar with the KEYDOWN but the example I was using used the KEYUP so I stuck with that (stupidness). I know better now.